# Scala macro annotations. Is there a way to get a typed AST of class when using macro annotation?

Tags: scala, types, macros

I use macro-notation to analyze a code inside a class, but the AST inside a marked class is not typed and TermNames/TypeNames is not expanded.

In simple cases I can use Context.typecheck(classAst) and obtain typed AST. But for more complex classes, an error occurs because the typechecker does not yet know the definition of the outer classes that are used inside the current class.